# Pointer Arithmetic and Read/Write in C

Tags: c, pointers, io, filesystems, system-calls

I am writing some very low-level C code to emulate a "file system" for a homework project.  The file system is made of fixed-size blocks (1024B) but a "file" is allowed to span multiple non-consecutive blocks.

I need to be able to write any kind of `void *buf` to a file with a function that mimics `write`.  Let's say we have the following signature `myWrite(int blockNum, void *buf, int nbytes`.

Let's say `nbytes` is greater than `1024` so I have to write to multiple blocks.   So I'd need to do something like:

```
int remainder = nbytes - 1024;
myWrite(firstBlock, buf, 1024);
myWrite(nextBlock, (buf + 1024), remainder);
```

`myWrite` calls the standard `write` function underneath, passing in similar arguments.

The problem is with the pointer arithmetic, C doesn't like when I do pointer arithmetic on a `void*`.  I get a `EINVAL` or `EARGS` (depending on Mac vs. Linux) saying that C doesn't like the pointer I passed to the `write` system call since it was produced via `void` pointer arithmetic.

The problem is, I don't know what kind of data type I will be writing.  Sometimes it's a `char *` and other times it's something custom like a `my_type *` that represents a struct from the program code.

Is there any way around this?  I need to have a generalized write like this.   My current implementation works most of the time, but sometimes it fails.

Comment: Assuming `buf` is declared as `void *` and that `1024` is a number of bytes, then `(unsigned char *) buf + 1024` should be OK.

Comment: Will this work for any data type?

Comment: If you are just writing out bytes the underlying type is irrelevant.

Comment: I still get Invalid argument in my write calls.  Interestingly when I do a similar thing but with read() I don't get errors.

Comment: Although formally incorrect, the `void *` pointer arithmetic should be no problem as every major compiler under Linux is doing the expected and documented operation.  I guess, your `buf` is too small or `nbytes - 1024` evaluates to a negative or too large number.  I suggest to run your program through `strace` and/or `valgrind`

Comment: It was a simple logic bug with nbytes going negative.  However, all of your information was very helpful as I am doing void* arithmetic elsewhere that benefited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick to using `void *`-pointers.

When the need for byte wise pointer arithmetic arises just cast the `void *`-pointer to `char *` (as `sizeof(char)` is defined to be equal to `1`):

```
int a[2] = {47, 11};
void * p = &a[0];

printf("%d\n", *((int *)p)); /* Prints 47. */

p = ((char *) p) + sizeof(a[0]); /* Increments p by sizeof(int) bytes. */

printf("%d\n", *((int *)p)); /* Prints 11. */
```

Also as a note,: To type integers describing amounts of memory or indexes use `size_t` as it is guaranteed to be wide enough to address/index everything on the machine the code is compiled for.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is with the pointer arithmetic, C doesn't like when I do pointer arithmetic on a `void*`

That's correct: C prohibits you from adding integers to `void*`, because it does not know how to convert the number to a number of bytes by which to advance the pointer. Normally, the multiplier can be derived from the type of the pointer. `void*`, however, does not have a type, hence C prohibits the arithmetic on it.

C does not mind if you do pointer arithmetic on other pointer types where the size is known. You can convert your `void*` pointer to a `uint8_t*` pointer, a `char*` pointer, or any other pointer to a type where `sizeof(*ptr)` is equal to `1`, and do the arithmetic on it right before doing the arithmetic operations:

```
myWrite(nextBlock, ((char*)buf) + 1024, remainder);
```

The functions themselves should continue taking `void*`.